# Belongs To User association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I just want to show the username who created the events. But when I try it says

```
undefined method `user_name' for nil:NilClass
```

This is my event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
end
```

And this is my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_many :events
end
```

And I am trying to show the user name in `html.erb` file like this.

```
<%= event.user.user_name %>
```

But I am getting this error.

So this is my create method in `events_controller`

```
def create

    @event = current_user.events.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

So what should I do for showing username in that page.

Thank You

Comment: Try `<%= @event.user.user_name %>` in the show.html.erb if you are planning to show the user_name(provided that you have a 'user_name' column in the users table) who created the event right after creation of the event.

Comment: now its says

undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please post your whole show.html.erb file if it contains anything other than `<%= @event.user.user_name %>` in the question.

Comment: Are you using devise ?

Comment: I can see that you don't have `user_name` field for that model. I believe that you wanted to have that field but you forgot to create one. You can add and migrate your database. What exactly the view are you trying to show it in?

Comment: Actually I added user_name field to my database I can see it and update it.No I am not using devise.

Comment: when you  created the user model like so rails g model blahblah .... Did you   add the association event:references

Comment: No, I didn't add But I added index when I create the user_id  to events like this. 

 add_column :events, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :events, :user_id

Comment: Could you show the `def show` action in events controller?

Comment: I don't want to show user name in show.html I want to show user name in event index.

And this is index action
 def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

Comment: I have edited your question and added some details from your comments to   be more specific about what you are expecting, please check again and see if my answer below helps you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here's the problem:

You want to show the event's user's name in index page but you can't be sure all events have one user associated with them. To avoid it you could use.

```
<%= event.user.try(:user_name) || 'No user associated' %>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer will get your app to work, it won't fix your problem.

The core issue is that your `Event` doesn't have an associated `User` object. This would not be a problem, except it seems from your code that you *require* an `Event` to have an associated `User` (`current_user.events.new` etc)...

You need the following:

```
#app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user 
   validates :user, presence: true #-> always makes sure user exists
   delegate :user_name, to: :user #-> event.user_name
end
```

--

If you use the above code, you'll be able to call `@event.user_name` (solving the [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) with [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate)). You'll also benefit from using [`validates presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) to ensure the `:user` association exists on create & update.

This will allow you to rely on the `@event.user` object, which - to me - is far better than having to say "No user associated" in your app:

```
#view
<%= @event.user_name if @event.user %>
```